# In VS Code, see dependencies from virtual environment using python and poetry Pylint(E0401:import-error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, python-poetry

For my project I use **poetry** to install all **python 3.10** dependencies. It works.

```bash
$ poetry env list
## .venv (Activated)
```

But in VS Code, **Pylint** do not recognise any installed library via poetry and the *Select interpreter* doesn't propose this `.venv` environment.

**How may I declare the right python environment `.venv` such that pylint find the installed libraries?**

I want to get rid of that:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
## Unable to import 'fastapi' Pylint(E0401:import-error)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode doesn't show poetry virtualenvs in select interpreter option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59882884/225020)

Comment: Thanks @Jab, I've tried it before asking, doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59957906/225020) to that question?

Comment: It doesn't work :( """update from 2022, "python.venvPath": is no more available in vscode – 
Xiang ZHU
 Oct 16, 2022 at 19:11"""

Comment: `python.envPath`?

Comment: Nope, `python.envPath` doesn't do anything

Comment: The 3rd section in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298947/how-to-debug-poetry-application-in-visual-studio-code works, but it is a manual workaround. Do you have any idea how to do it programatically? What should I have in `settings.json`?

Comment: What does `the Select interpreter doesn't propose this .venv environment` mean? If you select `+ Enter Interpreter Path ...` in the Select Interpreter panel, and then select `.venv`  environment interpreter through file management, is it okay?

Comment: @JialeDu When I add the output of `$ poetry env info --path` it works, but this is a manual solution. Is there any reproducible config to make in `.vscode/settings.json`?

Comment: You just have to choose an interpreter for the Python extension, you can also set the `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"`, but you still have to choose.